# Problem link id from activitymain to mainactivity

Tags: android, visual-studio, kotlin

I want to parse JSON from this URL https://swapi.dev/api/films/

Here my activity_mail.xml

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/mylist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And here my MainActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var pDialog: ProgressDialog
lateinit var listView: ListView
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val url="https://swapi.dev/api/films/"
}

inner class AsyncTaskHandler:AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
    override fun onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()
        pDialog= ProgressDialog(this@MainActivity)
        pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait")
        pDialog.setCancelable(false)
        pDialog.show()
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String?): String {
        //TODO("Not yet implemented")
        val res:String
        val connection=URL(url[0]).openConnection()as HttpURLConnection
        try {
            connection.connect()
            res=connection.inputStream.use { it.reader().use { reader->reader.readText()} }
        }
        finally {
            connection.disconnect()
        }
        return res
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        jsonResult(result)
        if(pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss()
    }

    private fun jsonResult(jsonString: String?) {
        val jsonArray=JSONArray(jsonString)

        val list=ArrayList<MyData>()
        var i = 0
        while (i<jsonArray.length())
        {
            val jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
            list.add(
                MyData(
                    jsonObject.getString("title"),
                    jsonObject.getInt("episode_id"),
                    jsonObject.getString("opening_crawl"),
                    jsonObject.getString("director"),
                    jsonObject.getString("producer"),
                    jsonObject.getString("release_date")

                )
            )
            i++
        }
        val adapter=ListAdapter(this@MainActivity,list)
        mylist.adapter=adapter
    }
}
```

}

The problem is that he dont find my listview "mylist". I put a id but at the end of the file i have this error : "Unresolved reference: mylist"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that ?             (ListView)(R.id.mylist).adapter=adapter

Answer (score 0):

R.layout.activity_main change to R.layout.activity_mail

Comment: Do u append listview tag in ur activity_main layout?